# How to direct to a page on the basis of response Angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular, router

I have two pages on my UI and i want to redirect the USER on the basis of HTTP response. PFB code .

```
 {
      "routerName": this.routerName,
      "serviceId" : this.serviceId,
      "serviceType" : ILL
}
```

Now my servicetype is ILL then i want to direct the page to ILL page and when the value service type is GVPN then i want to direct it to GVPN page.
PFB routerModule

```
RouterModule.forRoot([
      { path: 'ill' , component: IpIllComponent }, // Want to go to this page when service type is ILL
      { path: 'gvpn' , component: IpGvpnComponent } // Want to go to this page when service type is GVPN
    ])
```

Please help me on this.

Comment: After getting the response from your service you can redirect user using the method
this.router.navigate(['/${res.serviceType}']);
Dont forget to import Router from @angular/router

Answer (score 0):

You need to inject the router in your class and then use it to navigate:

```
constructor(private router: Router) {}

const path = response.serviceType === 'ILL'? 'ill' : 'gvpn';
this.router.navigate([path])
```

See docs: https://angular.io/guide/router

Comment: Can navigate it on the basis of RouterLink and button after getting the path value from response?

Comment: Yep I have tried routerLink="{{path}}". Its working
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
constructor(private router: Router, private http: HttpClient) {}

RouteByServiceResponse() {
    this.http.get(<url>).subscribe(response => 
        if ( response.serviceType === 'ILL' ) 
        {
            this.router.navigateByUrl('/ill');
        } else if ( response.serviceType === 'GVPN' ) {
            this.router.navigateByUrl('/gvpn');
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In runtime you can check the service type and then use `router.navigate` to navigate to a page which you want.

```
if (serviceType === 'ILL')
  this.router.navigate(['/ill'])
else
  this.router.navigate(['/gvpn']);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
constructor(private router: Router) {}

this.router.navigate(['/gvpn']);
```

Please follow this angular documentation. You will be find all your issue related to Angular routing.

[angular routing](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt5)